# open browser error in VSTS2008 for a Silverlight project

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, silverlight, visual-studio-2008

I am using Silverlight 2 + VSTS 2008 + C#. And I downloaded source code from the popular sl2videoplayer, http://sl2videoplayer.codeplex.com/ then I build the solution and then using F5 to debug (IE tries to open default.html). But seems the page cannot be opened, here is the screen snapshot. Any ideas what is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the project and was able to run without any problems in Internet Explorer. Have you any details to add specific to your situation?

Now, I'm on Silverlight 3, so VS2008 did convert the project when I opened it.

new edit: George, It occurred to me that I had [seen something like this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650735/cant-establish-connection-on-local-asp-net-development-web-server/674179#674179). Check out that q/a. It might help you out.

Comment: Yes, "default.html" exists. How to find whether ASP.NET Development Server is firing up using the port "1055"?

Comment: oops, sorry--I should have kept the original answer there. I was able to download and run as I stated above w/out issue. The only diff in our situations might be the SL2->SL3 conversion.

Comment: Thanks scottmarlowe, I am using Silverlight 2. Any more information do you need for analyze further?

Comment: You should see a tray icon that looks like a web page with a plus sign. Hover your mouse over it and it will show you the port. In my case, it also used port 1055.

Comment: George, sounds like you have an environment issue since I was able to get the source and run w/out issue. You might want to try another generic web app--create your own and see if you can bring that up.

Comment: Thanks scottmarlowe, you are so smart and correct! I have created a new ASP.Net web application (keep all defaults, no code change and just build and press F5), then the same error, this time the port number is 29114. The error screen is the same as I posted. Any ideas what is wrong and how to analyze further?

http://localhost:29114/Default.aspx

Comment: hmmm... no. are you admin on the box? I might also suggest you take this issue to the new superuser version of stackoverflow--www.superuser.com. See the latest blog post on the stackoverflow blog for instructions on how to access since it is just starting in beta. Good luck.